# Mercurial "hginclude"? (globbing syntax to specify which files to track)

Tags: mercurial

I was wondering if Mercurial or any of its extensions support a mechanism to **specify with  globbing rules what files to track** (i.e. a file that serves the opposite purpose of `.hgignore`).

I understand that I can use regular expressions in `.hgignore` to specify files to ignore (and hence, by exclusion, which ones to track), but I like the **globbing sintax** Mercurial supports for `.hgignore`, and was wondering if I could use the same syntax to specify which files to track.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative look-ahead assertion in `.hgignore`.  For example, you could use the following to only include C++ source files.  Note that all files you intend to match must be in the one regex.

```
(?!.*\.([ch](pp|xx)?|C|H))
```

However, I don't think you can do this with the globbing syntax.